# move a table view cell from one table view to a new table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Currently, I am able to move a tableview cell from one table view to another, but in the new tableview, I want to then move this cell from the section “Mark as done” to the section “History”. Right now the program runs, but then crashes on the line “goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])” with a ‘Fatal error: Index out of range’. How do I fix this?

Updated code for progress view.

```
let sections: [String] = [“Mark as Complete”, “History”]
var goals: [[String]] = []


extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if goals.indices.contains(section) {
        return goals[section].count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TodayGoalViewCell_1", for: indexPath) as? GoalTableViewCell
        cell?.goalLabel.text = goals[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell?.cellDelegate = self
        cell?.index = indexPath
        return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)
    goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])
    tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Regular goals view in a separate file. Here is the code:

```
var goals: [String] = ["goal 1", "goal 2", "goal 3"]
valueToPass = “ ”

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if segue.identifier = “GoalCell_1” {
    let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    viewController.goals.append([valueToPass])
    }
}

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return goals.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalCell_1", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = goals[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        valueToPass = goals[indexPath.row]
        PerformSegue(withIdentifier: “segue”, sender: self)
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            goals.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            goals.count != 0 {
                showGoalSelected()
                tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you move between the 2 views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by using a segue to move between the 2 rows you can use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath() function to get the goal selected and pass it to the progress view via the segue.
To do this you need and array in the progress view to accept the goals, which you have.

```
var goals: [String] = []
```

You will also need to set up a segue, the easiest way to do this is to ctrl click and drag from the viewController Icon at the top of the storyboard for your goals view and drop it on the view of the progressGoals. You get a dropdown to select the type of segue, choose 1. Then use the right hand menu to name the segue something memorable.

You also need a place to hold the goal to pass. Add this to your goals view.

```
var valueToPass = ""
```

Now implement the did select row function something like this.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
        //selects the goal from the goals array
        valueToPass = goals[indexPath.row]

        //trigger the segue to move views
        performSegue(withIdentifier: <yourseguename>, sender: self)
       
    }
```

Now in the segue pass the value to the progress goals view.

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if (segue.identifier == "yourseguename"){
            
            //this is the view controller of the where progress goals table is
            let viewController = segue.destination as! ViewController 
            //add the goal you selected to the array in you progress goals view. 
            viewController.goals.append(valueToPass)
        }
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. When I implement this into my code, it doesn’t display the information from the old tableview into the new one.

Comment: @Kar534 do you get any errors? Is the information being passed accross to the array in the progress view?

Comment: I don’t get any errors, and it appears that the information is not being passed.

Comment: I saw your other question I think you have 2 variables called goals 1 with upper case G and the other with lower case g, so are trying to access the wrong one in the second view.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now a new cell is added to the progress table view, but there is no text in the cell and when trying to add more than one goal, only one cel is present.

Comment: Ok so it is likely something to do with the goals array you have in the progress table view run a print statement to see what is stored in there. Maybe test it first as a simple array then add the complexity of the array of arrays with sections.

Comment: looking back at your other code there seem to be some naming errors to the segue idenfitier in the prepare for segue function is different to the one triggered by selecting the cell. Could you post the code you now have again?

Comment: Thanks for the help. My updated code is posted in this question.

Comment: Ok so where do you trigger the segue? What is the segue called? At the moment you have a segue identifier which is the same as the cell identifier?

Comment: So I’ve updated my code to match what I have. I am now able to move the cell from the original view to the progress view. However, I would like to take the cell that is now in the progress view section “Mark as done” and place it in the next section “history”. Any ideas on how I would do this?

Comment: When I run what I have up above, I receive “Fatal error: Index out of range” on the line, goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])

Comment: Ok you get the error because you remove it before you append it, so you need to switch the remove statement to be below the append statement.

Comment: the index out of range error is caused by trying to access an index in the array which doesn't exist. So this must be caused by the array not containing an item at goals[0][indexPath.row]

Comment: Is it that the array doesn’t contain an item at goals[0][indexPath.row] or that the tableView does not recognize that there is a second section of goals which I am asking for it to append the cell to? When I run the code by inputting a 0 for the 1 in the goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row]), the program runs but does not move the cell to the next section.

Comment: The array is not recognising there is a value at goals[0][indexPath.row].

Comment: Have you tried it like this? {goals[1].append(goals[0][indexPath.row])
goals[0].remove(at: indexPath.row)}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214402/discussion-between-joby-and-kar534).